# MongoDB deployment

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, atlas

I'm working on application with mongo DB, I'll host my app on AWS, is it better to host my DB on AWS or ATLAS? and is there a price better than the `Dedicated` price in atlas because it's much expensive (about 684$/year).

Comment: MongoDB Atlas uses AWS eventually. If you are familiar with AWS and some infra, you'd better go with AWS

Comment: what about price, is there a better price ?

Comment: As AWS provides infra, it's a better option in price